# Passing different set of arguments to the different commands in a linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-scripting, arguments

I am writing a bash script `foo.sh` that runs too commands `bar` with first input argument, and `baz` with the second argument:

```
#! /bin/bash
bar "$1"
baz "$2"
```

Now I want to make `foo.sh` more flexible, having optional number of arguments for `bar` and `baz`, something like the below:

```
./foo.sh bar_args="-x -v message=hello" baz_args="-d -m"
```

And I want `foo.sh` to pass `bar_args` as the input arguments to `bar`, and `baz_args` to `baz`. I want also `foo.sh` to work normally if either of the arguments were not given (for instance if `bar_args` is not provided, `bar` should be called without any arguments).

How to do this?

Comment: I would recommend examining a solution like getopt(s) as described in [this detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash). Getopt(s) in C possesses the ability to do exactly what you want, so I assume you should be able to reproduce that behaviour in Bash. Unfortunately, I've only the time to offer you a pointer and cannot walk you through the details of an implementation (as much as I'd like!)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a bash script solution however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it's a bit fragile

foo.sh will look like this

```
#! /bin/bash
declare "$@"       # evaluate the params as variable declarations
bar $bar_args      # not quoted!
baz $baz_args      # not quoted!
```

Then, `./foo.sh bar_args="-x -v message=hello" baz_args="-d -m"`
 will work like you hope.

Do not attempt to pass a message with whitespace in it, can't be done in this manner.